# How to take a mode of list of lists, through each list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a Python list of lists:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [1,3,3], [0,3,0]]
```

I want to take a mode of it, in this way:

mode of zeroth position of each list: `1, 1, 0` = 1 
mode of first position of each list: `2, 3, 3` = 3 
mode of second position of each list: `3, 3, 0` = 3

So, the output will be:

```
output = [1, 3, 3]   # expected output
```

Can anyone tell me, how to take such mode?

I tried using statistics library: `statistics.mode(a)`, but it is giving me this error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. Do you have any other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate in parallel over the lists:

```
from statistics import mode

a = [[1,2,3], [1,3,3], [0,3,0]]

res = [mode(x) for x in zip(*a)]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[1, 3, 3]
```

Comment: `list(map(mode,zip(*a)))` :p